# Syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'

Tags: linux, scripting, syntax

I have created a very simple script (see below) but cannot get it to run properly.  I always get messages saying

```
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'
line 5: 'fi'
```

when I try to execute this script.

```
#!/bin/sh
rm /opt/file_name
if $? -ne 0 then
    echo 'error'
fi
exit
```

I am running this on Red Hat Linux if that makes any difference.

If any one can help identify what is wrong with the if statement I'd really appreciate it.

Bill

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a semicolon (and I'm not sure if it works without square brackets).

Alternatives:

> if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then

or

> if ! test $? = 0; then

or

> if [ $? -ne 0 ];then

or

> test $? = 0 || echo 'error';

or even better:

> rm /bla/bla || echo 'error';

(the last one is your whole script)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a *very* handy alternative. The "test" command is itself a command like "rm". It sends a return code to "if": 0 if it succeeds and 1 or greater if it fails. So instead of checking the return code in the special $? variable, you can just do this:

```
if rm foo; then
    echo "It worked"
else
    echo "It failed"
fi
```

You can also negate the if by doing this:

```
if ! rm foo; then
     echo "It failed"
fi
```

Comment: Or excluding if entirely: rm foo || echo 'It failed';

Comment: And if you want to do more than one thing if it fails: rm foo || { echo 'It failed'; exit 1; }

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon at the end of that if statement as well as brackets:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm /opt/file_name

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

     echo 'error'

fi

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon or a line break between `if` and `then`, i.e.

```
if $? -ne 0; then
...
fi
```

or

```
if $? -ne 0
then
...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

rm somefile

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
     echo 'error'
fi

exit
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, square brackets and a line break work.
Bill